# Symfony2 - How to display data in a form row

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.7

I want to display for a choice field type more than just the label and the widget.

Assuming I have an array of stdclass objects :

Here's my controller code

```
$foo = new stdClass();
$foo->icon = 'fooicon.gif';
$foo->name = 'foo';

$bar = new stdClass();
$bar->icon = 'baricon.gif';
$bar->name = 'bar';    

$formdata->choices = array($foo, $bar);

$form = $this->createForm(new CustomForm(), $formdata);
```

Here's my form type

```
// FormType
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add() // Some other fields, not useful

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // There are some checks here ... let's summarize them by using true
        if (true) {
            $form->add('myChoices', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => $data->choices,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'choices_as_values' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
            ));
        }
    });
}
?>
```

template.html.twig

```
    {% if form.myChoices is defined %}
         {{ form_row(form.myChoices) }}
    {% endif %}
```

With this, I have a checkbox for each choice with the name as label. What I want to achieve is to display the icon and the name for each checkbox.
How can I do this ?

I am using symfony 2.7

Comment: Everything is here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html

Comment: I already read this, but I didn't find out how to get my choice data in these custom field blocks (i.e: my stclass object)

Comment: Replace [this line](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L49) with a custom block `form_label_icon`

Answer (score 0):

In Twig you can use for loop for getting multiple values with label.

Like the code below:

```
{% for myChoices in form.myChoices %}
    <label class="check">
        {{ form_errors(myChoices) }}
        {{ form_widget(myChoices) }}
        <span>{{ myChoices.vars.label }}</span>
    </label>
{% endfor %}
```